# headers and footers acting strangely with floatpag package

Tags: floats, header-footer, fancyhdr

Using the `fancyhdr` package, I have a LaTeX document with the following headers and footers:

- Underlined chapter name at the top of each page.
- Page number at the bottom of each page.

I was also advised to use the `floatpag` package because I want to remove the headers on pages with large sidewaysfigure plots.

Currently, the header is removed on my sidewaysfigure plots, but any regular figures that have a page on their own have the underline removed from their header, and the page number footer has moved to be a header.

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me please?

Comment: As you may have noticed, headers are removed on the first page of a chapter.  Actually, they are removed anytime one uses \thispagestyle.

Comment: Yes I have noticed. Sorry, I don't see how that relates to my issue.

Comment: Please show us the problem with an minimal working example.  Then we can copy it to our computers, run it, check the warnings and play with it to help you. As your questions stands now we can only guess ...

Comment: As it stands, the question is unclear. Please improve it.